# How to drop SQL Server database currently in use and in Single user mode

Tags: sql-server

I have a Database on SQL Server 2008, which I want to drop.
Currently it is in single user mode and it is currently in use.

```
select * from sys.sysprocesses
```

returns

```
Msg 924, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Database 'G_MAIN_DE' is already open and can only have one user at a time.
```

and I do not know how to identify the session I have to kill.

An attempt to set it offline

```
ALTER DATABASE G_MAIN_DE SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

yields

```
Msg 5064, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Changes to the state or options of database 'G_MAIN_DE' cannot be made at this time. The database is in single-user mode, and a user is currently connected to it.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

Comment: Thought I would add, in SQL Server 2016, sp_who returns some rows but an error saying the database is already open and can only have one user, etc - but the rows returned do not show the session that is tying up the database. sp_who2 does not return any rows at all, but only the error. sp_whoisactive does not return rows either, but two messages "Warning: The join order has been enforced because a local join hint is used." and then the error about the database being open "and can only have one user at a time." - in case anyone searches for those 3 proc names.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To identify the session currently using the database you can try

```
SELECT request_session_id
FROM   sys.dm_tran_locks
WHERE  resource_database_id = DB_ID('G_MAIN_DE')
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Finally there is peace in our land.

Answer (score 10):

This built-in stored procedure shows all connections to a database

```
exec sp_who2
```

And this query kills a connection to the database, for example connection SPID #53

```
exec kill 53
```

Comment: Note: The command is just `kill 53`, there's no `exec` at the beginning.

Comment: why is this stored procedure `sp_who2`? what happened to `sp_who`? Is `sp_who2` an updated version or something?

Comment: It can happen that sp_who, sp_who2 and sp_whoisactive fail to return any rows, but only show the same error about the database allowing only one user, etc. (Well actually sp_who does return some rows but no rows for the affected database).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to so is use SSMS Activity Monitor (Right-click server/Activity Monitor/Processes). Sort by Database. Kill whatever process has a hold onthe DB. You might also want to issue the kill command right before you set the DB to single-user and do the drop.

Answer (score -2):

if above process is not working,then go to services and kill the sqlservices in taskmanger. Then will be able to set to multiuser.